# Do you have to use zf tool when creating controller, model, action etc... in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am using zend framework 1.10. I use the zf tool to create controllers, actions and everything else. It is handy, but I am now seeing that when it modifies existing controller files to add new actions it realigns my code and removes some function closing brackets. I then see all these errors in eclipse. I see that everytime i issue a zf command it modifies the .zfproject file. Is this file critical at all? I want to be able to create whatever I want by myself without the zf tool and worrying about that .zfproject file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create everything even if you don't use zf tool. It is just an extra feature to speed things up. But it all boils down to preferences. If you know which files to create and where to create them. You can manually do it.

Comment: Any lists anywhere of what the manual equivalents of the zf CLI shortcuts would be?